# Box moving out of grid JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a yellow box in a grid. When click button 'UP' the yellow box is going one box UP. How can I stop the yellow box when it arrives at the edge? I do not want it to go out of the grid.

```js
let moveCounter = 0;

var grid = document.getElementById("grid-box");


for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  square.className = 'square';
  square.id = 'square' + i;
  grid.appendChild(square);
}
var playerTwo = []; 

while (playerTwo.length < 1) { 
  var randomIndex = parseInt(99 * Math.random()); 
  
  if (playerTwo.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    playerTwo.push(randomIndex);

    var drawPtwo = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawPtwo).addClass("p-1")
  }
};

$('#button_up').on('click', function() {
  moveCounter += 1;

  $pOne = $('.p-1')
  var id = $pOne.attr('id') 
  var idNumber = +id.slice(6);
  var idMove = idNumber - 10
  var idUpMove = 'square' + idMove;
  $pOne.removeClass('p-1');
  $('#' + idUpMove).addClass('p-1');

});
```

```css
#grid-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#grid-box>div.square {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.p-1{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-box"></div>

<div class="move">
    <button id="button_up">UP</button>
    <br>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

I am new to Javascript / jQuery. Any help will be much appreciated ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```js
let moveCounter = 0;

var grid = document.getElementById("grid-box");


for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  square.className = 'square';
  square.id = 'square' + i;
  grid.appendChild(square);
}
var playerTwo = []; 

while (playerTwo.length < 1) { 
  var randomIndex = parseInt(99 * Math.random()); 
  
  if (playerTwo.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    playerTwo.push(randomIndex);

    var drawPtwo = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawPtwo).addClass("p-1")
  }
};

$('#button_up').on('click', function() {
  moveCounter += 1;

  $pOne = $('.p-1')
  var id = $pOne.attr('id') 
  var idNumber = +id.slice(6);
  var idMove = idNumber - 10;
  if(idMove < 0){idMove +=10;}
  var idUpMove = 'square' + idMove;
  $pOne.removeClass('p-1');
  $('#' + idUpMove).addClass('p-1');

});
```

```css
#grid-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#grid-box>div.square {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.p-1{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-box"></div>

<div class="move">
    <button id="button_up">UP</button>
    <br>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Here I have added the condition which restrict box to out of the grid

if(idMove < 0){idMove +=10;}

if movable position is in the minus then it again initialise it existing position.

Comment: Thank you very much! what if I wanna do the same thing but with a DOWN movement. it should be: if(idMove > 100){idMove +=10;} ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check to stop it from moving out of the squares

```
var idMove = idNumber - 10
if(idMove > 0){
   // do all the moving stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` statement to check `idMove > 0)` If it is, then you can move your square, if it isn't then you shouldn't move your square. it will be `undefined`, and so you can run your code only when `pOne`'s `id` is not undefined.

See example below:

```js
let moveCounter = 0;

var grid = document.getElementById("grid-box");


for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  square.className = 'square';
  square.id = 'square' + i;
  grid.appendChild(square);
}
var playerTwo = [];

while (playerTwo.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(99 * Math.random());

  if (playerTwo.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    playerTwo.push(randomIndex);

    var drawPtwo = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawPtwo).addClass("p-1")
  }
};

$('#button_up').on('click', function() {
  moveCounter += 1;

  $pOne = $('.p-1')

  var id = $pOne.attr('id')

  var idNumber = +id.slice(6);
  var idMove = idNumber - 10
  if (idMove > 0) {
    var idUpMove = 'square' + idMove;
    $pOne.removeClass('p-1');
    $('#' + idUpMove).addClass('p-1');
  }
});
```

```css
#grid-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#grid-box>div.square {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.p-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-box">
</div>

<div class="move">

  <button id="button_up">UP</button><br>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button_up').on('click', function() {
  moveCounter += 1;

  $pOne = $('.p-1')
  var id = $pOne.attr('id') 
  var idNumber = +id.slice(6);
  var idMove = idNumber - 10;
  if(idMove > 0) {
    var idUpMove = 'square' + idMove;
    $pOne.removeClass('p-1');
    $('#' + idUpMove).addClass('p-1');
  }
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, do you mind explaining what you changed exaclty?